# Synchronization algorithm for deterministic context switching between threads

Tags: python, algorithm, multithreading, synchronization

Curious how sqlite3 would handle different race conditions in a multithreaded environment, I created a simple module called `deterministic` for serializing the execution of multiple threads that lets the programmer explicitly program in the spots where thread-switching happens.  Hopefully this example usage will explain the idea better:

```
import deterministic

def main():
    deterministic.run(consumer0, consumer1, consumer2)

def consumer0():
    print('consumer 0 yields to consumer 2')
    yield 2
    print('consumer 0 exits')

def consumer1():
    print('consumer 1 yields to next consumer')
    yield
    print('consumer 1 exits')

def consumer2():
    print('consumer 2 yields to consumer 1')
    yield 1
    print('consumer 2 yields to next consumer')
    yield
    print('consumer 2 exits')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Which outputs:

```
consumer 0 yields to consumer 2
consumer 2 yields to consumer 1
consumer 1 yields to next consumer
consumer 2 yields to next consumer
consumer 0 exits
consumer 1 exits
consumer 2 exits
```

Again, the idea is to experiment with how real multi-threaded code behaves, but in a highly controller environment.

The actual code follows below.  Some specific feedback I'm hoping for:

- Is there a synchronization primitive that better models what I'm trying to do than simple locking?
- Even if not, is there a better way to structure the code to make it easier to reason about?
- Finally, general coding and style advice is more than welcome

---

```
import threading, time, types

def run(*consumers):
    sync = Syncrhonizer(len(consumers))
    _run_threads(
        threading.Thread(target=DeterministicRunner(sync, i, c).run)
        for i, c in enumerate(consumers)
    )

class Syncrhonizer:
    def __init__(self, num_instances):
        self._instances = list(range(num_instances))

        self._lock = threading.Lock()
        self._current = 0
        self._want_abort = False

    def lock(self, idx):
        while True:
            self._lock.acquire()

            if self._want_abort:
                self._lock.release()
                raise SyncrhonizerAbort()

            if self._current == idx:
                return

            self._lock.release()
            time.sleep(0.001)

    def die(self):
        self._want_abort = True
        if self._lock.locked():
            self._lock.release()

    def yield_to(self, idx=None):
        if idx is None:
            idx = self._get_next_instance()

        if idx not in self._instances:
            self.die()
            raise Exception('Can not yield to non-existent instance "%s"' % idx)

        self._current = idx
        self._lock.release()

    def _get_next_instance(self):
        try:
            return next(n for n in self._instances if n > self._current)
        except StopIteration:
            return self._instances[0]

    def remove(self, idx):
        self._instances.remove(idx)
        if self._lock.locked() and self._instances:
            self.yield_to()

class SyncrhonizerAbort(Exception):
    """Abort execution because of an issue in another thread"""

class DeterministicRunner:
    def __init__(self, syncer, idx, method):
        self._syncer = syncer
        self._idx = idx

        self._g = method()
        if not isinstance(self._g, types.GeneratorType):
            raise Exception('Not a generator')

    def run(self):
        try:
            while True:
                self._syncer.lock(self._idx)

                n = next(self._g)

                self._syncer.yield_to(n)
        except StopIteration:
            pass
        finally:
            self._syncer.remove(self._idx)

def _run_threads(threads):
    threads = list(threads)

    for t in threads:
        t.start()

    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Threading

Trying to use `time.sleep` with `threading.Lock`s usually means you’d be better of using a [`threading.Condition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#condition-objects) instead. It lets you wait passively instead of using an active `while True: ... time.sleep(0.001)`.

However, in your case, you could simplify further using a [`threading.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects):

```
class Synchronizer:
    def __init__(self, num_instances):
        ...
        self._lock = threading.Event()

    def lock(self, idx):
        while self._current != idx:
            self._lock.wait()
            if self._want_abort:
                raise SynchronizerAbort()
        self._lock.clear()

    def die(self):
        self._want_abort = True
        self._lock.set()

    def yield_to(self, idx=None):
        ...
        self._current = idx
        self._lock.set()
```

Every thread, except the `0`\$^{th}\$ one, will enter the `while self._current != idx` loop and wait for the `Event` to become available. Once available after thread `0` exits `yield_to`, only the one with the right ID will exit the loop and all the others will wait on the `Event` to be set again.

Now what have we here? Every thread needing to wait at a synchronization point, loop until a condition becomes available, and check for a flag that indicates if an other thread went through an error… Time to change for a [`threading.Barrier`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#barrier-objects) (Python 3.2 and up).

There is a drawback to using barriers, in that they must be reached by **all** threads before they are all released at once. Meaning we can't let `DeterministicRunner.run` exit before all threads are done. So we must have `Synchronizer.lock` return a boolean value indicating if we are running out of instances or not.

```
class Synchronizer:
    def __init__(self, num_instances):
        ...
        self._barrier = threading.Barrier(num_instances)

    def lock(self, idx):
        while True: # Force any thread to enter, independently of its idx
            self._barrier.wait()
            if not self._instances:
                # All threads exit at once when everything is done
                return False
            if self._current == idx:
                # Only the active thread can exit otherwise
                return True

    # No need of `die` anymore
    def yield_to(self, idx=None):
        if idx is None:
            idx = self._get_next_instance()

        if idx not in self._instances:
            self._barrier.abort() # Make all other thread abort with BrokenBarrierError
            raise Exception('Can not yield to non-existent instance "%s"' % idx)

        self._current = idx
```

## Coding Style

It is recommended that

```
import threading, time, types
```

is written

```
import threading
import time
import types
```

However, since you’re making very little use of `time` and `types` I’d rather recommend the `from .. import ..` form.

Other than that, there is little to talk about. It is mostly a matter of taste:

- converting the generator parameter of `_run_threads` into a list could be done using the variable-length argument syntax:

  ```
  def _run_threads(*threads):
      for thread in threads:
          thread.start()

      for thread in threads:
          thread.join()
  ```

  and call it with `_run_threads(*(<generator_expression>))`.
- `DeterministicRunner.run` might be better written with the `try` within the `while` to reduce the amount of protected code:

  ```
  def run(self):
      while True:
          self._syncer.lock(self.idx)
          try:
              n = next(self._g)
          except StopIteration:
              self._syncer.remove(self.idx)
              break
          else:
              self._syncer.yield_to(n)
  ```

  note that when using barriers, you have to `while self._syncer.lock(self.idx):` and not `break`.
- `Synchronizer._get_next_instance` might be more readable using plain list iteration:

  ```
  def _get_next_instance(self):
      for n in self._instances:
          if n > self._current:
              return n
      return self._instances[0]
  ```
- I'd check that the methods returns an object that has a `__next__` method rather than being of type `GeneratorType`. It allows for more flexibility for anyone using your API and wanting to provide a custom class rather than generator functions.

You are also using a custom made exception for cleanup purposes but you use generic `Exception`s for errors in using your API. I'd go the other way around and use custom exceptions that are easier to handle for real errors and generic ones for cleanup.

## Proposed Improvements

```
import threading


class SynchronizeError(Exception):
    """Abort execution because a thread does not respect the API"""


class Synchronizer:
    def __init__(self, num_instances):
        self._instances = list(range(num_instances))
        self._current = 0

        self._barrier = threading.Barrier(num_instances)

    def lock(self, idx):
        while True:
            self._barrier.wait()
            if not self._instances:
                return False
            if self._current == idx:
                return True

    def yield_to(self, idx=None):
        if idx is None:
            idx = self._get_next_instance()

        if idx not in self._instances:
            self._barrier.abort() # All other threads get BrokenBarrierError
            raise SynchronizeError(
                'Can not yield to non-existent instance "{}"'.format(idx))

        self._current = idx

    def _get_next_instance(self):
        if self._current >= self._instances[-1]:
            return self._instances[0]
        for n in self._instances:
            if n > self._current:
                return n

    def remove(self, idx):
        self._instances.remove(idx)
        if self._instances:
            self.yield_to()


class DeterministicRunner:
    def __init__(self, syncer, idx, method):
        self._syncer = syncer
        self._idx = idx

        self._g = method()
        if not hasattr(self._g, '__next__'):
            raise SynchronizeError('Not a generator')

    def run(self):
        while self._syncer.lock(self._idx):
            try:
                n = next(self._g)
            except StopIteration:
                self._syncer.remove(self._idx)
            else:
                self._syncer.yield_to(n)


def _run_threads(*threads):
    for t in threads:
        t.start()

    for t in threads:
        t.join()

def run(*consumers):
    sync = Synchronizer(len(consumers))
    _run_threads(*(
        threading.Thread(target=DeterministicRunner(sync, i, c).run)
        for i, c in enumerate(consumers)
    ))
```

Comment: This is great advice. I like how you show the progression through threading.Event to threading.Barrier. I found my original threading.Lock code hard to reason about, while in contrast your threading.Barrier code is relatively easy to reason about.

Comment: Good observation about what type of Exception to throw. Also I like your advice about checking for `__next__` and for reducing the amount of protected `try..except` code.

Comment: @MichaelKropat I find barriers pretty neat, but as I said, it can have its drawbacks. That being said, since we know that threads will terminate all at once, we can `join` on only one of them (namely the last one which is still in `t`). But that could be error-prone if you ever decide to change from barriers...